# Button color Issue in Linux platform

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

The Button color is not getting updated rather didn't show normally as well as dynamically when i run my application. this problem occurs only on Linux environment and the same code work fine with windows.

```
 private JButton button = new JButton();
                button.setLayout(buttonLayout);
                button.add(totalsLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                totalsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
                button.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
                button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                button.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
                button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                button.setEnabled(true);
                button.setPreferredSize(PREFERRED_SIZE);
                button.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
                button.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
                button.setFocusPainted(false);
                button.setBackground(mementoTO.getBackGroundColor());
                private void initializeAlternatingColorsThread() {

                alternatingColors = new Thread(new Runnable()  {
                    public void run() {
                        while(true)  {
                            while(continueAlternatingColors())  {
                                try {
                                    if(button.getBackground().equals(BACKGROUND_PAY_LATER)) {
                                        button.setBackground(BACKGROUND_BUSY); }
                                    else {
                                        button.setBackground(BACKGROUND_PAY_LATER); }
                                    Thread.sleep(500); }
                                catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                                    getLogger().error(this + " - Error occured in initializeAlternatingColorsThread: ", ex);   }   }
                            synchronized(lockVariable) {
                                try {
                                    lockVariable.wait();    }
                                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                                } } } }
                }, "AlternatingColors");  }


    GuiExecutor.getInstance().update(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setStaticText("RESETTING PUMP");
                        setStatus("HANG UP NOZZLE");
                        button.setBackground(BACKGROUND_BUSY);
                        button.repaint();
                    }   });
```

If i go ahead with windows look and feel then i am getting below exception in Linux. So I changed the look and as GDK for Linux.

```
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 | Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI.getMinimumSize(BasicButtonUI.java:352)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1714)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.BorderLayout.minimumLayoutSize(BorderLayout.java:651)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.minimumSize(Container.java:1651)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.995 |     at java.awt.Container.getMinimumSize(Container.java:1636)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at javax.swing.JComponent.getMinimumSize(JComponent.java:1716)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at java.awt.FlowLayout.minimumLayoutSize(FlowLayout.java:448)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/01/21 15:14:23.996 |     at
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not respect Swing threading rules. You should change a component's properties on the Swing event thread (the EDT) only. Use a SwingWorker to do this and your problems will likely go away.

Better yet, why not simply use a Swing Timer?

Also your code formatting is poor (for example -- `} } } }` ) making it hard for us to read your code and help you. Please put in the effort to post better formatted code here if you desire us to put in the effort to help you.

Comment: i got the place where I am getting this exception.

button.add(totalsLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
totalsLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
button.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);

Comment: @user1280096: please note any changes as an addition to your original question. Edit the original question, add new code to the end and new explanations as well, and then comment our answers to notify us of the changes.

Answer (score 3):

This...

```
alternatingColors = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (continueAlternatingColors()) {
                try {
                    if (button.getBackground().equals(BACKGROUND_PAY_LATER)) {
                        button.setBackground(BACKGROUND_BUSY);
                    } else {
                        button.setBackground(BACKGROUND_PAY_LATER);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    getLogger().error(this + " - Error occured in initializeAlternatingColorsThread: ", ex);
                }
            }
            synchronized (lockVariable) {
                try {
                    lockVariable.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, "AlternatingColors");
```

Is violating Swing's single thread rules - You must never create or update any UI component out side of the Event Dispatching Thread, doing so can result in, as you have found, unexpected behavior.

You should be using a `SwingTimer` to perform the same task...

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information